# wp_editor customization

Tags: filters, hooks, tinymce, buttons

I've been stuck in a simple issue for the last couple of hours:

I'm developing a website in which I use several wp_editor instances, all with custom buttons and styles. This is very simple to achieve by just adding the arguments directly to the wp_editor, in my custom posts.

My issue resides in trying to add custom buttons to ONLY the editor used for the standard regular Wordpress posts. This is because I did not create the instance manually, and I assume I have to use a filter function.

Here is how I'm adding the arguments in my wp_editor instances in my custom posts:

```
<?php
wp_editor(
    $options['news_title'],
    'news_title',
    array(
        'textarea_name' => 'page_options_home_page[news_title]',
        'media_buttons' => false,
        'textarea_rows' => 1,
        'tabindex' => 4,
        'quicktags' => false,
        'tinymce' => array(
            'toolbar1'=> 'bold,italic',
            'toolbar2'=> '',
            'toolbar3'=> '',
            //'content_css' => get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce/page-options-mce-editor.css"
        ),
    )
);
?>
```

Here is how I would add a GLOBAL style to the wp_editor - also very simple, **BUT this approach does not work for me** as it affects all my other instances.

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    //styles for the editor to provide better visual representation.
    $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
    $in['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 1=h1; Heading 2=h2";
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'formatselect,bold,italic,underline,superscript,bullist,numlist,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,spellchecker';
    $in['toolbar2'] = '';
    $in['toolbar3'] = '';
    $in['toolbar4'] = '';
    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```

So...I'm trying to find some direction on how to target that specific wp_editor. In general, I'm having trouble passing arguments to specific wp_editor that I did not manually create (regular post editor, bbpress,etc). I want to remove a few button instances of those editors and keep them in my custom ones.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use the [`get_current_screen()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) function to get what screen the current user is on ( in the admin panel ) and only add those global values whenever the user is viewing the `post` page:

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if( is_object( $screen ) && 'post' == $screen->post_type ) {
        //styles for the editor to provide better visual representation.
        $in['content_css'] = get_template_directory_uri() . "/build/styles/tiny-mce-editor.css";
        $in['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p; Heading 1=h1; Heading 2=h2";
        $in['toolbar1'] = 'formatselect,bold,italic,underline,superscript,bullist,numlist,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,link,unlink,spellchecker';
        $in['toolbar2'] = '';
        $in['toolbar3'] = '';
        $in['toolbar4'] = '';
    }

    return $in;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_format_TinyMCE' );
```